# How to keep ascii art intact when using it inside React projects

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ascii-art

I want to use the following [art](https://www.asciiart.eu/animals/aardvarks):

```
     _.---._    /\\
    ./'       "--`\//
  ./              o \
 /./\  )______   \__ \
./  / /\ \   | \ \  \ \
   / /  \ \  | |\ \  \7
    "     "    "  "        VK
```

In react I am doing the following:

```
const x = String.raw`
  _.---._    /\\
  ./'       "--`\//
./              o \
/./\  )______   \__ \
./  / /\ \   | \ \  \ \
 / /  \ \  | |\ \  \7
  "     "    "  "        VK`
```

I have also tried using the  tag but most of those characters are appearing as errors

EDIT:
so this does not get deleted I am explicitly mentioning that I am using some different assets from that website, alot of them do not work when you just copy past because they appear as errors in the ide, I am using VSCode. Yes for some I can just copy paste the thing and its fine, for others it does not work

Comment: have you tried to simply include it as a string in your code and displaying it as  `<pre>` 
 HTML element. it preserves whitespace and formatting, so the ASCII art will be displayed as intended.

Comment: Why is the question closed if none of answers work...

I cannot just paste it as is because alot of the characters appear invalid with a red squiggly line at the bottom

Comment: Hi, are you saying that using pre does not work for you? You can edit your question for example putting in a runnable snippet which shows the problem when you use pre and see if it can be reopened.